# Page can't keep history data

Tags: javascript, php, html, history

I have a form that contains dynamic inputs(added with addRow() function) the problem is that when I click on the submit button. the form sends data to another page (second page), but if there are errors, the second page back to the first page, but the problem is that the form page does not keep inputs with data.

The first page

```
<table  id="tab">
   <tr>
      <th>Ref</th>
      <th>Designation</th>
      <th>Prix d'achat</th>
      <th>Prix de vente</th>
      <th>Qte</th>      
      <th>Remise</th>       
      <th>Montant</th>      
      <th>action</th>       
   </tr>
</table>
```

The function that adds a line inputs

```
<script>
function AddRow_v(nbrn){    
    var newRow = document.getElementById('tab').insertRow(-1);
    var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
    newCell.innerHTML = "<td><div class='input_container'><input type='text'  class='input_80 valider' name='ref[]' id='ref_id"+nbrn+"' onkeyup='autocomplet("+nbrn+")' />  <ul id='produits_list_id"+nbrn+"' style='display:none;'></ul></div></td>";
    newCell = newRow.insertCell(1);
    newCell.innerHTML = "<td><input type='text' name='designation[]'  id='designation_id"+nbrn+"'  /></td>";                                        
    newCell = newRow.insertCell(2);
    newCell.innerHTML = "<td><input type='text' id='px_achat"+nbrn+"'  name='px_achat[]' class='input_60 only_number' /></td>";
    newCell = newRow.insertCell(3);
    newCell.innerHTML = "<td><input type='text' id='px_vente"+nbrn+"'  onkeyup='calculez("+nbrn+");' name='px_vente[]' class='input_60 only_number' /></td>";
    newCell = newRow.insertCell(4);
    newCell.innerHTML = "<td><input type='text' id='qte"+nbrn+"'  onkeyup='calculez("+nbrn+");' name='qte[]' class='input_30 only_number' /></td>";
    newCell = newRow.insertCell(5);
    newCell.innerHTML = "<td><input type='text' id='remise"+nbrn+"'  onkeyup='calculez("+nbrn+");' name='remise[]' class='input_30 only_number' /></td>";
    newCell = newRow.insertCell(6);
    newCell.innerHTML = "<td><input type='text' id='montant"+nbrn+"'  readonly name='montant[]' class='input_60 only_number' /></td>";
    newCell = newRow.insertCell(7);
    newCell.innerHTML = "<td><a onclick='remove_v("+nbrn+");' id='remove"+nbrn+"' class='btn' rel='tooltip' data-original-title='Supprimer'><i class='icon-remove'></i></a>";
    document.getElementById('nbrligne').value=count_ligne();

}
```

The second page

```
<?php
if(error()){
?>
<script>
    window.history.go(-1);
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Thank you for help

Comment: Yes, it's time for you to learn AJAX.

Comment: Could also $_POST the inputs back and forth, just make sure they are clean